# using if statement count number of notes given in amount

Tags: php, if-statement

i have a assingment and i am so confuse i dont know how to solve my problem,

Assingment :

Make a system which should have the capability to analyze the total number of possible notes in a given amount using only if statement,

**Example**
**Input:**

```
Input amount: 575
```

**Output**

Total number of notes:

```
500: 1
100: 0
50: 1
20: 1
10: 0
5: 1
2: 0
1: 0

plese tell me how i write code of this,
```

i need your help i don't know how i make this,

Comment: If the number is bigger, how will be the output? For example, if the number were 1057, the output must start with 1000?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys won't change:

```
<?php

function getPossibleNotes($input, $keysArray = [500, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1])
{
    $responseArray = array_combine($keysArray, array_fill(0, count($keysArray), 0));

    foreach($keysArray as $comparison){
        if($input >= $comparison){
            $input -= $comparison;
            $responseArray[$comparison] = 1;
        }
        if($input <= 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    return $responseArray;
}

//When Input = 575

print_r(getPossibleNotes(575));

/*
    Array
    (
        [500] => 1
        [100] => 0
        [50] => 1
        [20] => 1
        [10] => 0
        [5] => 1
        [2] => 0
        [1] => 0
    )
*/
```

Edit: if you need the count of the notes (As I see in other answers), do this replacement:

```
$responseArray[$comparison]++;
```